# How to convert the result of externalHeight() to REM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I could adjust the font size of the root HTML to fit the HTML window, for example:

```
        var inputFont = parseFloat($("html").css("font-size"));
        if (inputFont)
            $("html").css("font-size", inputFont * 0.9);
```

Prior to this adjustment, I could make some elements fit to each other, for example:

```
         buttonElem.outerHeight( $(labelElem).outerHeight() );
```

So, I would need to repeat this again, or to set the height in REM for buttonElem from the beginning, right?

Do you know how to quickly convert the result of externalHeight() to REM? 
Will this conversion help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

calcREM() function is added:

```
function calcREM(px)
{
    if( !isNaN(px) )
    {
        var remInPx = parseFloat($("html").css("font-size"));
        return (parseFloat(px) / remInPx).toString() + "rem";
    }
}
```

The code above has been updated to:

```
buttonElem.outerHeight( calcREM($(labelElem).outerHeight()) );
```

---

Here is the test.

The buttonElem before.
[image: The buttonElem before]

The buttonElem after converting pixels to REM using the calcREM () function.
[image: The buttonElem after the update]

---

Note: my CSS includes the definition:

```
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a CSS class to set the height in `rem` directly instead of using JavaScript at all?

Comment: The code is a part of JQuery plugin and the pugin can be applied to any <select..>. The buttonElem  is dynamically created.